# Exclude rows that don't have any data in them in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tweaked this script to validate all cells in the M column for specific data:

```
function Phoned()
    {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 
    var option = new Array();
    option[0]="Attempt 1";
    option[1]="Attempt 2";
    option[2]="Dead";
    var dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();
    dv.setAllowInvalid(false);
    dv.requireValueInList(option, true);
      sheet.getRange("M2:M").setDataValidation(dv);
    }
```

And while it works, it also adds the validation to blank rows, as shown here:

[image]

I have tried to use something like this to ignore blank rows:

```
var range_input = sheet.getRange("M2:M").getValues();
var filtered_input = range_input.filter(String);
```

..and then feeding that back into the data validation, but I think my thought process is incorrect here, as the filter will extract the data from those columns, whereas I just need to exclude the actual blank rows from the getRange query.

I have also tried to use this (which essentially removes all blank rows) but it seems that query commands cannot be used inside of scripts, otherwise it would probably work.

```
sheet.getRange("QUERY(test!A:N,"SELECT * where A is not null")").setDataValidation(dv);
```

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Your `getRange` call selects every row in the worksheet except for the first. If you want to do something else - like select only up to a given row - then change this call. See this and other variations: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)

Comment: Hi there, i understand that i could change it to e.g. M2:M240 (or whatever) but the key here is that I don't set a hard end point, and the formula automatically grows as more data is added. If I paste in another 1000 rows, i would like the script to dynamically change the M2:M240 to M2:M1240. Make sense?

Comment: And? That is perfectly addressable. Do more research into methods available, especially for the `Sheet` class

Comment: With all respect, I have spent a couple hours doing research into different methods, and I am unable to find a solution, probably due to my limited understanding of the code. I have however, tried my best (as you can see with the examples above) and thus I feel comfortable  asking for some help here.

Comment: Have you tried using `var myValidationRange = sheet.getRange(2, 13, sheet.getLastRow());`? (The reason your filtered array doesn't work is because you are working with a JavaScript array of the row contents, and not the `Range` class - `Range#getValues()` returns an `Array[][]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked nicely! I added it here - sheet.getRange(2, 13, sheet.getLastRow()).setDataValidation(dv); 

I had to research a little about what the 2, 13 represented but I understand it to be row 2 of the 13th column. There is one small issue, it seems to add one additional row, I presume because it it was offset in the beginning by one, see here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yi8qjfj5pji1dj/2.png - any way to "minus" a row from the "last cell" query? Also, I would be happy to tip you for your help, I appreciate your time so let me know. :)

Comment: Also @tehhowch please add your answer as an answer and then I can choose it as a solution for others to easily view?